# log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"

Tags: java, log4j

estoy intentando configurar un log rotativo.
Estoy utilizando log4j-1.2.17.jar y apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar.

mi configuración en el fchero log4j.properties es el siguiente:

```
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.append=true
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:/logs/_Agenda/agendaNojCRONBATCH_%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss}.log
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.rollingPolicy.activeFileName=C:/logs/_Agenda/agendaNojCRONBATCH.log
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.triggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=52428800
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_BATCH.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Pero cuando levanto el servidor me arroja los siguientes errores:

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [triggeringPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy". 
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy". 
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'LOG_CRON_BATCH'
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Tiene pinta de que alguno de los parámetros está mal. ¿`FileNamePattern` quizá? No respeta las convenciones empezando con mayúscula